# printf behavior and ASCII code

Tags: pointers, printf, ascii

I stumbled on the following piece of code in an interview question, and I'm curious about how printf works in such a situation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
double m[]={10.711680659488273,580};    
int main() {    
m[1]--?m[0]*=2,main():printf((char*)m);
return 0;
}
```

The question is that you're asked to change the initial values in the array so that the printf function prints your full name.
I'm curious as to how printf behaves in such a situation.
Thanks.

Comment: This company should be sued for discrimination - nobody with a name longer than 8 characters can pass this test!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, strings are represented by their address. When you write `"Hello"`, the text **Hello** will be put "somewhere" in the memory, but where you have actually written that `"Hello"`, an address will appear (it is a `const char*`). So whenever you pass a format string to `printf`, you always pass the address of a format string, a pointer. And here, `printf` gets a pointer, just it is cast to `char*` from a `double*` (when you use an array variable without indexing into it, you just get the address of its first element), but it is a pointer. The text itself is coming from the 10.711680659488273*2^580, and the null terminator comes from the 0 (what remains from that 580 at the end).

You can check the internals of that double at http://www.binaryconvert.com/convert_double.html for example, and copy the resulting hexadecimal or binary number into an other converter, like https://paulschou.com/tools/xlate/ (just remember to **not** copy the 0x in case of hexadecimal). You can already see a large part of the result (`LeKhal`), and the rest appears when the multiplications are executed. As binary floating point numbers are represented by a mantissa and an exponent for 2, multiplying them by 2 alters the exponent only. Since you already have the conversion page open, you can track how the bits in the exponent change (that is easy, it just steps by 1, or 580 times in total), and how it affects the resulting 16-bits (recognize that the exponent does not start on a byte-boundary).